# College scorecard only has 40 states?

Tags: collegescorecard, programming

So I just downloaded the college scorecard datasets and import into R, I used a unique() function on "STABBR" and it only returned 40 unique values for states, what happened here?

Comment: I was unable to replicate the issue (viewing the data files in Excel). Can you provide more details about the particular file(s) and which states appear to be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I just started working with this data so I don't have a ton of experience with it, but I downloaded all data from https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/ and just looking at the 'Merged2014-15-PP.csv' table I have 59 distinct state codes.